# Convert Current Image to Black and White

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

The goal is to convert the current image in GUI window to black and white

Below is my code:

```
def BlackAndWhite(self):

        from images import Image
        
        LoadAFile = self.inputText.getText()
        CurrentImage = open(LoadAFile)
        image = self.image = PhotoImage(file = LoadAFile)
        image.draw()
        BlackAndWhite(image)
        image.draw()
        self.imageLabel["image"] = self.image
        
          
        blackPixel = (0,0,0)
        whitePixel = (255,255,255)
        for y in range(image.getHeight()):
            for x in range(image.getWidth()):
                (r,g,b) = image.getPixel(x,y)
                average = (r+b+g) /3
                if average < 128:
                    image.setPixel(x,y,blackPixel)
                else:
                    image.setPixel(x,y, whitePixel)
```

I am getting this error message:

> ```
> image.draw()
> AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'draw'
> ```

Comment: `PhotoImage` is a subclass of `Image`, and neither has a `.draw()` method, hence the error. What I don't understand is what you wanted to do by calling that method in the first place. Are you looking for `.place(x, y)`, maybe?

Comment: I don't know any other way to convert the image to black and white

Answer (score 0):

Here's working code, you should be able to tweak it to work with your work:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, NW
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000)
canvas.pack()
img = Image.open("PATH_TO_AN_IMAGE")

blackPixel = (0, 0, 0)
whitePixel = (255, 255, 255)

for y in range(img.height):
    for x in range(img.width):
        pixelVal = img.getpixel((x, y))

        # Unpacking in this way in case the pixel contains more than R, G, B (ex: a png)
        r, g, b = pixelVal[0:3]

        average = (r + b + g) / 3
        if average < 128:
            img.putpixel((x, y), blackPixel)
        else:
            img.putpixel((x, y), whitePixel)

photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

canvas.create_image((20, 20), anchor=NW, image=photoimage, state="normal")
root.mainloop()
```